# Apply gravity force to static body in cocos 2d v3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, gravity, chipmunk

I've several static bodies and I want them behave like planets. Each static body should have gravity like force to affect on dynamic bodies. Currently I'm applying applyForce:atLocalPoint to dynamic bodies if distance to them less that some value. But current implementation do not behave like gravity, objects are start rotating and moving not to the centre of static bodies. Is the predefined behaviour in cocos 2d v3 with chipmunk for such behaviour?